# String literals in JS API query

Tags: javascript, api, xmlhttprequest, restful-url

I'm currently utilizing the MTG API SDK (https://api.magicthegathering.io) that has a query structured as such:

```
// partial name match
mtg.card.where({name: 'Archangel Avacyn'})
.then(results => {
    console.log(results)
})
// exact name match
mtg.card.where({name: '"Archangel Avacyn"'})
.then(results => {
    console.log(results)
})
```

I have a REST API trying to access the SDK on the server by passing in a string value for the exact name of the card you want to find, like this:

```
exports.getCard = (req, res) => {
    const card = req.params.card;
    let query = "'\"" + card + "\"'";
    console.log(query);

    mtg.card.where({name : query})
    .then(result=>{
        res.send(result);
    });
    
}
```

My problem is that is I use the variable `req.params.card` in the query I get the partial match return and if I use the `query` variable I get nothing. I need to exact match.

How can I get the exact match from passing in a variable instead of static text?

Comment: shouldn't `"'\"" + card + "\"'"` just be `'"' + card + '"'` or `\`"${card}"\``?

Comment: Doh. String literals, template literals, template strings. When will it end?

Comment: @Andy literally never. :P I'll see myself out.

Comment: To explain this: the data you're sending is `'"test"'` (not `'test'`). You were composing the characters you'd write in your code, but they also contain the delimiters which you don't need when composing the API request data.

Comment: Are you sure that the value you are testing with has an exact match? I'm not familiar with the specific API - but based on your above explanation of what makes exact/partial match, what you have written should indeed produce an exact match request. That said I probably would write it as `\`"${card}"\``.

Comment: @dacodr Right, you fixed it. Now please read my comment and understand that OP was sending the search term wrapped in two sets of quotes.

Comment: @ChrisG Seems that is intentional - see examples at top of his post. Also you can see it in the docs https://docs.magicthegathering.io/#advancedcards_get_by_name

Comment: @dacodr Using `{name: '"Archangel Avacyn"'}` in your code sends `"Archangel Avacyn"`. But OP was *sending* `'"Archangel Avacyn"'`

Comment: @ChrisG Oh yep! Missed the extra quote - thanks